# JOLT to split JSON into smaller parts - update 2021/06/08

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm getting some data in Nifi that collects JSON but the table that it needs to be inserted in has a different format.

I'm having trouble to deconstruct a JSON structure into smaller pieces - getting stuck with the second what seems like a two or three-part shift. Any ideas to get me to the next step?

**Original JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "inverterId": "Id159946.3",
    "timestamp": "2021-06-03 10:35:00.000",
    "COS_PHI": 0.998,
    "E_DAY": 85.6419916666667,
    "E_INT": 1.9674496666666663,
    "E_INT_N": 0.05,
    "E_TOTAL": 1142,
    "ERROR1": 0,
    "F_AC": 50.05200000000001,
    "I_AC": 96.96799999999999,
    "I_AC1": 32.322,
    "I_AC2": 32.318,
    "I_AC3": 32.327999999999996,
    "I_DC": 42.013999999999996,
    "I_DC1": 14.184000000000001,
    "I_DC1_1": 7.191999999999999,
    "I_DC1_2": 6.869999999999999,
    "I_DC2": 13.898,
    "I_DC2_1": 7.194,
    "I_DC2_2": 6.593999999999999,
    "I_DC3": 13.931999999999999,
    "I_DC3_1": 7.03,
    "I_DC3_2": 6.798,
    "I_DC4": null,
    "I_DC4_1": null,
    "I_DC4_2": null,
    "I_DC5": null,
    "I_DC5_1": null,
    "I_DC5_2": null,
    "OT_AC_TOTAL": 94,
    "P_AC": 23609.395999999997,
    "P_AC_N": 0.62,
    "P_DC": 24096.873999999996,
    "Q_AC": 953.1700000000001,
    "QS_CI": 100,
    "QS_RX": 1116,
    "QS_TX": 1116,
    "R_ISO": 20000,
    "STATE1": 0,
    "STATE2": 131073,
    "T_WR": 35.394,
    "U_AC": 243.76000000000002,
    "U_AC1": 243.628,
    "U_AC2": 244.3,
    "U_AC3": 243.35199999999998,
    "U_DC": 573.1573333333333,
    "U_DC1": 570.628,
    "U_DC2": 572.452,
    "U_DC3": 576.3919999999999,
    "U_DC4": null,
    "U_DC5": null,
    "systemKey": "K9V2Q"
  },
  {
    "inverterId": "Id159946.2",
    "timestamp": "2021-06-03 10:40:00.000",
    "COS_PHI": 0.998,
    "E_DAY": 118.47494700000001,
    "E_INT": 1.7862204999999998,
    "E_INT_N": 0.03,
    "E_TOTAL": 1270,
    "ERROR1": 0,
    "F_AC": 50.038,
    "I_AC": 91.154,
    "I_AC1": 30.296,
    "I_AC2": 30.392000000000003,
    "I_AC3": 30.465999999999998,
    "I_DC": 31.753999999999998,
    "I_DC1": 4.226,
    "I_DC1_1": 3.852,
    "I_DC1_2": 0.378,
    "I_DC2": 4.088,
    "I_DC2_1": 4.074,
    "I_DC2_2": 0.04000000000000001,
    "I_DC3": 8.074,
    "I_DC3_1": 4.138,
    "I_DC3_2": 3.898,
    "I_DC4": 7.584,
    "I_DC4_1": 3.806,
    "I_DC4_2": 3.7119999999999997,
    "I_DC5": 7.782,
    "I_DC5_1": 3.972,
    "I_DC5_2": 3.7439999999999998,
    "OT_AC_TOTAL": 79,
    "P_AC": 21434.645999999997,
    "P_AC_N": 0.34,
    "P_DC": 21971.543999999998,
    "Q_AC": 901.4119999999999,
    "QS_CI": 100,
    "QS_RX": 1119,
    "QS_TX": 1119,
    "R_ISO": 20000,
    "STATE1": 0,
    "STATE2": 131073,
    "T_WR": 41.766000000000005,
    "U_AC": 240.552,
    "U_AC1": 241.614,
    "U_AC2": 239.54,
    "U_AC3": 240.50199999999998,
    "U_DC": 692.9512,
    "U_DC1": 806.782,
    "U_DC2": 599.358,
    "U_DC3": 631.958,
    "U_DC4": 817.722,
    "U_DC5": 608.936,
    "systemKey": "K9V2Q"
  },
  {
    "inverterId": "Id159946.3",
    "timestamp": "2021-06-03 10:40:00.000",
    "COS_PHI": 0.998,
    "E_DAY": 86.9375756666667,
    "E_INT": 1.295584,
    "E_INT_N": 0.03,
    "E_TOTAL": 1143,
    "ERROR1": 0,
    "F_AC": 50.038,
    "I_AC": 65.03800000000001,
    "I_AC1": 21.674,
    "I_AC2": 21.678,
    "I_AC3": 21.686,
    "I_DC": 28.126,
    "I_DC1": 9.486,
    "I_DC1_1": 4.824,
    "I_DC1_2": 4.548,
    "I_DC2": 9.234,
    "I_DC2_1": 4.822,
    "I_DC2_2": 4.2940000000000005,
    "I_DC3": 9.406,
    "I_DC3_1": 4.77,
    "I_DC3_2": 4.524,
    "I_DC4": null,
    "I_DC4_1": null,
    "I_DC4_2": null,
    "I_DC5": null,
    "I_DC5_1": null,
    "I_DC5_2": null,
    "OT_AC_TOTAL": 94,
    "P_AC": 15547.008,
    "P_AC_N": 0.41,
    "P_DC": 15971.436000000002,
    "Q_AC": 810.6179999999999,
    "QS_CI": 100,
    "QS_RX": 1122,
    "QS_TX": 1122,
    "R_ISO": 20000,
    "STATE1": 0,
    "STATE2": 131073,
    "T_WR": 35.664,
    "U_AC": 242.69133333333335,
    "U_AC1": 242.72,
    "U_AC2": 243.30200000000002,
    "U_AC3": 242.05199999999996,
    "U_DC": 566.1546666666667,
    "U_DC1": 561.5440000000001,
    "U_DC2": 567.3480000000001,
    "U_DC3": 569.572,
    "U_DC4": null,
    "U_DC5": null,
    "systemKey": "K9V2Q"
  }
]
```

**JOLT Spec:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "timestamp": "[&1].timestamp",
        "inverterId": "[&1].inverterId",
        "systemKey": "[&1].systemKey",
        "I_DC*_*": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The above lets me at least filter the fields I need but now needs a new field (stringId) to be created from the I_DC*_* fields and the value of that in the original json put into the "value" field.

This is the desired output at the end:

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2021-06-03 10:35:00.000",
    "systemKey": "K9V2Q",
    "inverterId": "Id159946.3",
    "stringId": "I_DC1_1",
    "value": 7.191999999999999  
  },{
    "timestamp": "2021-06-03 10:35:00.000",
    "systemKey": "K9V2Q",
    "inverterId": "Id159946.3",
    "stringId": "I_DC1_2",
    "value": 6.869999999999999
  },{
    "timestamp": "2021-06-03 10:35:00.000",
    "systemKey": "K9V2Q",
    "inverterId": "Id159946.3",
    "stringId": "I_DC2_1",
    "value": 7.194  
  },{
    "timestamp": "2021-06-03 10:35:00.000",
    "systemKey": "K9V2Q",
    "inverterId": "Id159946.3",
    "stringId": "I_DC2_2",
    "value": 6.593999999999999  
  }
]
```

If you have any tips to do this without Jolt in Nifi let me know - busy trying that now as gave up on Jolt for the day.

Thanks!

**Edit 2021/06/08:**
I managed to use this spec to extract the I_DC*_* fields and get them in the position I need. I'm still struggling to keep the inverterId, timestamp and systemKey inside each of these arrays like the desired output shown above. Any hints?

Spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "I_DC*_*": "[].&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "[#3].stringId",
          "@": "[#3].value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "stringId": "I_DC1_1",
    "value": 7.191999999999999
  },
  {
    "stringId": "I_DC1_2",
    "value": 6.869999999999999
  },
  {
    "stringId": "I_DC2_1",
    "value": 7.194
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "timestamp": "[&1].timestamp",
        "inverterId": "[&1].inverterId",
        "systemKey": "[&1].systemKey",
        "I_DC*_*": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "timestamp": "[&1].timestamp",
        "inverterId": "[&1].inverterId",
        "systemKey": "[&1].systemKey",
        "*": "[&1].keysToPivot.&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "keysToPivot": {
          "*": {
            "$": "[&3].[#2].stringId",
            "@": "[&3].[#2].value",
            "@(2,timestamp)": "[&3].[#2].timestamp",
            "@(2,inverterId)": "[&3].[#2].inverterId",
            "@(2,systemKey)": "[&3].[#2].systemKey"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Please test it, let me know if any issues.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! Just one question as this is where I got stuck in mine:
In the second shift, why does this part ("*": "[&1].keysToPivot.&") not catch the timestamp, inverterId and systemKey keys? Does Jolt filter out keys that have been "captured" in previous entries (e.g. where you have "timestamp": "[&1].timestamp")?

Comment: The ( * )  wildcard can be used by itself or to match part of a key but it won't match keys that were already mapped in the JSON. Hence this expression ("*": "[&1].keysToPivot.&") does not match/include the timestamp, inverterId and systemKey keys.